# How do I exclude South migrations from Pylint?

Tags: python, django, django-south, pylint

I'm using South for migration in my Django project. When I run Pylint on my project I get a bunch of errors from the migration files. How can I exclude migration files from Pylint?

I'm on a Windows system so I can't use filename exclusions in the Pylint options. I've tried to resort to adding `# pylint: disable-msg-cat=WCREFI` to the top of each of my migration files. It seems very kludgy and seems to be the last resort but this documented directive doesn't work and I get the error `[E] Unrecognized file option 'disable-msg-cat'`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding the following to the `.pylintrc` file did it.

```
[MASTER]

# Add <file or directory> to the black list. It should be a base name, not a
# path. You may set this option multiple times.
ignore=tests.py, urls.py, migrations
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, need to use ignore-paths with a regex instead

Answer (score 2):

```
# .pylintrc
ignore-patterns=\d{4}_.*?.py
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25983565)

Answer (score 2):

The anser here didn't work for me, the ignore list doesn't work on directories.
I had to add

`ignore-paths=.*/migrations`

Comment: I needed `.*/migrations/*` for it to work with pylint 2.14.5

Answer (score 1):

In recent pylint versions, disable-msg-cat has been unified with other disable-* options
as a single 'disable' option. Since then,

```
# pylint: disable=I,E,R,F,C
```

may be added on top of files where you don't want any messages issued.